# Google Location API and Google Map Android API don't work suddenly

Tags: android, google-play-services, google-maps-android-api-2

My codes have been working greatly for a long time.
Today it doesn't work suddenly. I thought it was because of the recent update for Google Play Service, so I update the version of Google Play Service to the newest version, but no luck.

The below are the logs, please check:

03-24 10:59:04.041    8669-8669/com.xxx.sciencex.xxxx W/ResourcesManager﹕ Asset path '/system/framework/com.android.media.remotedisplay.jar' does not exist or contains no resources.

03-24 10:59:04.041    8669-8669/com.xxx.sciencex.xxxx W/ResourcesManager﹕ Asset path '/system/framework/com.android.location.provider.jar' does not exist or contains no resources.

03-24 10:59:04.059    8669-8669/com.xxx.sciencex.xxxx I/Google Maps Android API﹕ Google Play services client version: 7095000

03-24 10:59:04.070    8669-8669/com.xxx.sciencex.xxxx I/Google Maps Android API﹕ Google Play services package version: 7097438

Comment: Kind of the same situation here, but in our case app does work on most of devices but not on Samsungs. Still investigating if it's related to new Play Services somehow, but switching to `7.0.0` did not helped

Comment: I also switched to 7.0.0, and also no luck. Please update your solution if you find any. I will do the same. Thanks.

Comment: @Dmitry, Somehow, my codes works fine now. I don't know why. I don't think I made any changes. Good luck.

Comment: If someone got the answer of this I would gladly vote up the answer...

Comment: Means no one have an answer, 31-0ct-18?